# How to handle json payload in GET request Play 2.0 + Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I want to make a handler/controller for a GET request such as in ElasticSearch :

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?routing=kimchy' -d '{
"query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "query_string" : {
                "query" : "some query string here"
            }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
        }
    }
}}
```

I read the documentation from http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaJsonRequests but the example is based on POST request. I've tried on my own it appears that I can access to the body request with POST request. But, when I try with the GET request, my request.body is AnyContentAsEmpty.

Is there a way to handle the json from this request in Play 2.0 ?

---

I saw that there is no body semantic for GET : [Payloads of HTTP Request Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905916/payloads-of-http-request-methods) .
So maybe it's normal that there is no mechanism to deal with it through Play 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are confused on what can you expect on each type of request. To sum it up:

1. **GET** requests contain the payload in the URL, no request body is
   added
2. **POST** requests add the payload to the request body

From the example you post it seems that you want to return a Json answer as a result from a GET request, which would make more sense.

That can be easily achieved by crafting the Json string and using the `Ok(result).as("application/json")` to set the MIME type of the response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think I didn't well explain my problem. I don't want to create an handler that return json. I want to create an handler that can read json from a GET request. My example is the basic example from elasticsearch with curl. You perform a GET (-XGET from curl) request to the elasticsearch server with json. Then  the elasticsearch server returns the json result of the search. Maybe I don't understand how works the curl cmd in this case. My guess is that -d force the request to use POST: _-d Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server_

Comment: As I said in my post, in regards of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905916/payloads-of-http-request-methods) it seems possible to send request bodies within GET request. Therefor it's highly recommand to avoid such thing. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @alexgindre yes, GET uses the URL, POST the body. With -d you are doing a POST request, sending json by GET could be done by encoding it and adding it as a parameter, but I believe it's not a good option, better use POST.

Comment: @yesterday thank you for your help! The curl cmd deceived me with -d param. Even it seems possible to use GET as I would, the playframework doesn't support this because it's too unorthodox, I guess. I will use POST or PUT.

Answer (score 0):

[this is a sample question](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4606)

*Play's default body parser follows the HTTP spec, and ignores the message body for GET, DELETE, HEAD and OPTIONS methods. If you want to force it to parse a body, you can do that by explicitly passing a body parser, eg:*

```
 def delete = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
   val json = request.body
   val someProp = (json \ "someprop").as[String]
   Ok(s"Prop is: $someProp")
 }
```