# RESTful DELETE with a comment

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have a RESTful API. `DELETE /Collection/<Object-ID>` will delete the specified object. We don't delete the objects internaly. It will only marked as deleted.

Now it is required to enter a delete comment. How is this possible with REST?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323716/restful-alternatives-to-delete-request-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a **custom http header** on the request from the client, and then read it from the server.

**Edit:**

Example for request with custom header:

```
DELETE /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Delete-Comment: not needed anymore
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
Date: Thu, 14 Nov 2013 13:56:26 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Note that X-Headers are deprecated: [Custom HTTP headers : naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions/3561399#3561399)

Answer (score 3):

You have many options (as outlined [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323716/restful-alternatives-to-delete-request-body)), but none of them are really considered standard practice. I personally would avoid using custom HTTP headers, but then you might run into trouble with certain HTTP implementations disallowing (or even ignoring) request bodies when sending DELETEs.