# Reason behind GET/DELETE cannot have body in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Why do `HttpMethod`s such as `GET` and `DELETE` cannot contain ***body***?

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(Uri requestUri);
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteAsync(string requestUri);
```

also in Fiddler, if I supply a body, the background turns red. But still it will execute with body on it.

[image: Fiddle Image]

So as an alternative, I used `SendAsync()` because it accepts `HttpRequestMessage` which can contain `HttpMethod` as well as the *content*.

```
// other codes
Category category = new Category(){ Description = "something" };
string categoryContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(category);
string type = "application/json";

HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, "-page-")
HttpContent content = new StringContent(categoryContent, Encoding.UTF8, type);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

message.Content = content;
await client.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
// other codes
```

Did I missed something else?

Comment: Maybe these two articles could help you. [RESTful Alternatives to DELETE Request Body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323716/restful-alternatives-to-delete-request-body) and [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Comment: Is there any special reason why you want to send a body with a GET or DELETE request? In general, there is no reason to use a body in these type of requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per HTTP standards, GET method is aimed to retrieve data, hence there is no need to provide a request body.

Adding a request body violates the rules defined. This is therefore prohibited.

The same applies to DELETE method.

Comment: Since HTTP 1.1 Delete can have a body, it is just not always handled.See more at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/299696/2151623)