# Angular $http delete request body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

There is the following code:

```
params =
  method: 'DELETE'
  url: "profiles/#{@currentProfile.id}/boxes/#{@box.id}/messages"
  data:
    ids: ids
  headers:
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" 
$http(params)
```

When I execute this DELETE request I see that this request has no body, i.e. my request has no "ids" param in the body. How can I fix it? I saw some answer on StackOverflow, where people gave advice to set 'Content-Type' header. I did it, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Depending on your backend - a body in the delete request might be being ignored.

Comment: @tymeJV - no, I look at Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools

Comment: _"my request has no 'ids' param_" - What do you mean by _param_? You send JSON not parameters.

Comment: @zeroflagL I mean request body ("data" key of my "params" var)

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your configuration ([codepen](http://codepen.io/fracz/pen/KdEeZq)). You can see in the dev tools that the request body is sent fine:

```
params =
  method: 'DELETE'
  url: "someurl"
  data:
    ids: [1,2,3]
    something: 'anything'
  headers:
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" 
$http(params)
```

[image: DELETE request body]

Keep in mind that some backends will ignore the DELETE body by default. Try to redesign you API.

Have a look at:

- [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)
- [RESTful Alternatives to DELETE Request Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323716/restful-alternatives-to-delete-request-body)