# Spark's DELETE handler returns NULL when accessing any request.queryParams key

Tags: java, postman, spark-java

I developed a very simple API using the Spark Framework (ref: sparkjava.com).  I wrote a delete handler and tested it with Postman.

### The Problem

When I try to assign a value using `request.queryParams`, a NULL value is assigned even though the data is in the HTTP request and shows up in `request.body`.

###### My Java:

```
delete("/threat", (req,res) -> {
    System.out.println("DELETE /threat");
    System.out.println("tid = "+ req.queryParams("tid"));
    res.status(200);
    return "done";
});
```

###### The Postman Request/Response

```
DELETE http://localhost:4567/threat 200 7ms
Request Headers
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
   Accept: */*
   Postman-Token: 90615059-38c6-4901-9838-249b36c35887
   Host: localhost:4567
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Length: 40
Request Body
   tid: "839c9af2-9ab4-495d-883b-3cd509b8116d"
Response Headers
   Date: Wed, 15 Dec 2021 22:03:02 GMT
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
   Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)
Response Body
   done
```

###### Console output

```
DELETE /threat
tid = null
```

If I output `req.body()` then it outputs `tid=839c9af2-9ab4-495d-883b-3cd509b8116d`, but it is strange that the output is `null` when trying to get `req.queryParams("tid")`.

###### Testing I've done

If I use `post()` instead of `delete()` it works!  The script outputs:

```
POST /threat
tid = 839c9af2-9ab4-495d-883b-3cd509b8116d
```

###### The question for the community

So before I go and write up my own body parser for the delete handler, can anybody tell me why `req.queryParams("tid")` returns null inside a `delete()` handler?

###### Research I've done

Googled, searched StackOverflow, read through the docs at SparkJava.com

###### Maven information (taken from my pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: thanks to @Aravinth for helping me find this information via their post: [Swagger openApi Spec 3.0 - DELETE opeartion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939681/swagger-openapi-spec-3-0-delete-opeartion) .)

Payloads on a DELETE are not supported.  While this is not *de jure*, it appears Spark Java abides by not supporting payload retrieval via `queryParams`.

RFC7231 states:

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

(Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3)