# GET HTTP request payload

Tags: java, api, http, get, elasticsearch

I am designing an API and I wonder if it is fine to send a JSON payload on a GET request?

In this other question [Payloads of HTTP Request Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905916/payloads-of-http-request-methods), we can find according to [this link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-14):

- HEAD - No defined body semantics.
- GET - No defined body semantics.
- PUT - Body supported.
- POST - Body supported.
- DELETE - No defined body semantics.
- TRACE - Body not supported.
- OPTIONS - Body supported but no semantics (maybe in the future).

**Does this mean that I should not send a GET request with a payload?**
Are there risks to do so?

- Like having some HTTP client libraries incapable of sending such a payload?
- Or my Java API code not being portable on certain application servers?
- Anything else?

---

I found out that ElasticSearch was using such a payload on a GET request:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?routing=kimchy' -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "some query string here"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

So if this popular libary does it and nobody complains, then perhaps I can do the same?

By the way, **I would like to know if this is OK to mix queryString parameters and JSON payload?** Exactly like this ElasticSearch query does. If so, are there rules so that we know which arguments should be queryString parameters, or payload parameters?

---

Here we can read:
[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

> Roy Fielding's comment about including a body with a GET request.
>
> Yes. In other words, any HTTP request message is allowed to contain a
> message body, and thus must parse messages with that in mind. Server
> semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body, if any,
> has no semantic meaning to the request. The requirements on parsing
> are separate from the requirements on method semantics.
>
> So, yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful to
> do so.
>
> This is part of the layered design of HTTP/1.1 that will become clear
> again once the spec is partitioned (work in progress).
>
> ....Roy

Then I don't really understand why it is never useful, because it makes sense in my opinion to send complex queries to the server that wouldn't fit well on queryParam or matrixParam.
I think ElasticSearch API designers think the same...

---

I am planning to design an API which can be called like that:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9000/documents/inbox?pageIndex=0&pageSize=10&sort=title'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9000/documents/trash?pageIndex=0&pageSize=10&sort=title'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9000/documents/search?pageIndex=0&pageSize=10&sort=title' -d '{
    "someSearchFilter1":"filterValue1",
    "someSearchFilter2":"filterValue2",
    "someSearchFilterList": ["filterValue3","xxx"]
    ... a lot more ...
}
'
```

**Does it seem fine to you?** Based on the above considerations.

---

Comment: One risk would be that client libraries wouldn't allow payloads to be sent in a GET request. I didn't even realize you could do this with curl, honestly.

Answer (score 3):

Having the GET response vary based on the request body will break caching. Don't go there.

Comment: This is an API where I don't need caching because it is contextualized by an OAuth2 header which identifies the client. Different clients can have different representations of the same resource URI so I can't do caching based on the resource URI

Comment: Are all intermediaties/libraries aware of that as well?

Comment: for sure because they need to get access of a OAuth2 token which permits them to manipulate an user account. Thus the /profile resource is the user profile for which the client has the OAuth2 token (given as a Header)

Comment: Since you mentioned about ElasticSearch, well, every the GET request with an endpoint such as /_search and /_count has, as a compromise, a POST counterpart.

Answer (score 3):

Also see: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) - for more detail on this.

The gist is: Yes you can, but you probably shouldn't for various reasons, including:

- You're likely ignoring HTTP spec recommendations (you probably want to POST)
- You may introduce caching issues
- This is **not** intuitive as far as REST APIs go

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine, a popular web framework, uses a special url fetch library, which [does not support making HTTP GET requests with a payload](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Fetching_URLs_in_Python).  Accordingly, if you want your API to reach Google App Engine users, then I would not recommend requiring this behavior.

I've opened [an issue regarding this](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10506&thanks=10506&ts=1390204913) with google.

Comment: Note that if you need to make a `GET` request, you can urlencode the body of the request in the `source` query-string parameter instead of sending it with the body of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you *should*. I'm sorry if this sounds infuriatingly tautological but the thing about standards is that they're *standard* - and HTTP is one of the most established standards there is. It's not perfect, and there are a lot of things which a lot of people would like to change about it, but the fact that nearly everyone is still using URL parameters for use cases such as this is to me sufficient indication that there aren't any reliable alternatives right now.

The answers from speedplane and Julian Reschke give two concrete examples of things that will break if you rely on GET requests with a body/payload. You can write your app differently to everyone else, if you want, but the web is one area where standards should perhaps be taken even more seriously than normal. I know it's tempting to be a trailblazer, but with all due respect, consider just how many websites exist, and how many web programmers there are building and maintaining them. If there was a definitively better way, you'd most likely see it widely used in production by now.

Standards change/are adopted slowly because so many people have to agree on them for them to work. You're correct in saying that there *are* applications that break the rules, but you'll notice they've caused headaches for people, and workarounds/redundancy measures are required in certain cases, as mentioned by Aetherus in their comment on another answer. I tend to take the path of least resistance on issues like this. If you really want to do it, I'm sure you can make it work, though.

Comment: I suspect that a lot depends on who is expected to consume the API. If the sole consumer is yourself, and you write the code that runs at the endpoint(s), I suspect you would be safe in using a GET.