# Correct response for HTTP GET with a Content-Type

Tags: http, get, content-type

What is the correct response for HTTP GET with a Content-Type? Should we respond with an error or should we ignore the Content-Type and process the request?

Comment: technically it's incorrect to have a content-type on a get, since get has no "body", therefore can't have any content. if you want to reject an obviously mal-formed request, go right ahead.

Comment: @MarcB I want to confirm this since spec does not talk about it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 7231 section 3.1.1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5):

> A sender that generates a message containing a payload body SHOULD
> generate a Content-Type header field in that message unless the
> intended media type of the enclosed representation is unknown to the
> sender.  If a Content-Type header field is not present, the recipient
> MAY either assume a media type of "application/octet-stream"
> ([RFC2046], Section 4.5.1) or examine the data to determine its type.

So, anything that has a "body", a payload, in the request, should pass in a Content-type.

GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS most often don't have such a payload. But the [might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360351/get-http-request-payload). So depending on the request method to determine if there is a body or not is not a very safe way.

If your server receives a GET, and it has a body, and that body is not `application/octet-stream` then it should have a `Content-Type` header. It is safe to send a `406 - Not Accepted` back when you receive such a request.

On the other hand, if your server does not handle body on a GET, then it would be safe to send a `406 - Not Accepted` back too.