# REST API: Is it acceptable to PUT to resource containing query param filters?

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm designing an API Service that returns only JSON representations.

Some background and context to my question... Behind the scenes a product in my database has an associated set of prices. Prices consist of (`qty`, `currency_code`, `unit_price`) tuples. Each set of prices belong to a particular product and price list.

Here's a glance at the relational database data. Each row has a unique constraint on (`product_id`, `price_list_id`, `currency_code`, `qty`). Both `product_id` and `price_list_id` are forreign keys.

```
dev=# SELECT * FROM
        price
      WHERE
        product_id = 1 AND price_list_id = 1 AND currency_code = 'GBP';
 id |                 uuid                 | product_id | price_list_id | qty | currency_code | unit_price |          created           |          modified          
----+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------+-----+---------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | 6fcbbb5b-8e51-4a4c-bf63-270f5d3f1ff8 |          1 |             1 |   1 | GBP           |      20417 | 2019-08-15 15:49:19.508808 | 2019-08-15 15:49:19.508808
 16 | c044e9fe-bb5f-4996-b8e6-88b4a1b9f125 |          1 |             1 |   2 | GBP           |    3453345 | 2019-08-15 15:49:37.896681 | 2019-08-15 15:49:37.896681
 17 | c488d372-e58f-4441-a583-281e4c2b1310 |          1 |             1 |   3 | GBP           |  312353345 | 2019-08-15 15:49:41.320622 | 2019-08-15 15:49:41.320622
```

To retrieve a set of prices for a given product I intend to use a `GET` request to the `/products/:product_id/prices?price_list_id=1&currency_code=GBP` resource. I expect to receive:

```
[
  { id: "6fcbbb5b-8e51-4a4c-bf63-270f5d3f1ff8", "qty": 1, "unit_price": 20417 },

  ... etc  // 3 items total
]
```

If I want to update a set of prices for a given (`product_id`, `price list_id` and `currency_code`), is it acceptable to do the exact reverse by doing a `PUT` request to the same URI that I used for the `GET`, i.e., `PUT /products/:product_id/prices/price_list_id=1&currency_code=GBP` or should I use an alternative?

In the context of a `GET` request having `price_list_id=1` and `currency_code=GBP` act like filters. Whilst using a `PUT` request I'm not sure if it's okay to identify a resource for updates using a query parameter as a filter.

Alternatives I've considered are:

1. `PUT /products/:product_id/prices` and place the `price_list_id` and `currency_code` in the request body. e.g.

```
{
  "price_list_id": "<uuid>",
  "currency_code": "GBP",
  "data": [
    { "qty": 1, "unit_price": <newprice> },
    ...  /* new set of prices */
  ]
}
```

thereby deleting all existing prices and replacing the set with those in the request body.

2. `PUT /products/:product_id/prices/price-lists/:price_list_id` which starts to look very long winded. `products` have many `prices` so the first part of the resource looks okay to nest as a subresource. However, `prices` don't have `price-lists` (it's the opposite way around) so it makes no sense to have `price-lists` as a sub resource of prices.
3. `PUT /prices/:price_id`. This means I have to first retrieve a list, delete them one by one and update prices individually. This is not a good solution as I want to operate on prices as a set collectively. I also want the set to be replaced as a whole or none at all.

Answer (score 0):

The url you are sending a PUT request to should be the 'identity' of the thing you are updating. Including information to locate the resource inside the request body does therefore *not* make sense.

All the information the server needs to 'locate' the resource you are updating should be in the resource locator (that's the url!)

All of these are completely fine from a HTTP protocol perspective:

1. `PUT /products/:product_id/prices?price_list_id=1&currency_code=GBP`
2. `PUT /products/:product_id/prices/price-lists/:price_list_id`
3. `PUT /prices/:price_id`

It doesn't really matter if your ids are in the path part of query part of the url, it should be irrelevant. For purposes of locating resources there's no difference between `/article/5` and `/article?id=5`.

So which one you choose should be based on consistency within your own API, user-friendliness, etc.

It's interesting that you don't like option 2 for being too long-winded, but you're ok with option 1 which is even longer though ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You're right about 1 and 2. Actually, they are both long winded. The real problem with 2 is the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PATCH /products/:product_id/prices`

See this answer to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32101994/853837