# ReST API for replacing multiple resources for PUT

Tags: rest

A good practice to name a PUT request is like:

> /employee/123

What if I want to replace several employees? Is it a good practice to do so in single request? If yes, then how to name the url with multiple ids?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REST: Updating Multiple Resources With One Request - Is it standard or to be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098423/rest-updating-multiple-resources-with-one-request-is-it-standard-or-to-be-avo)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can remove multiple employs using a single URL
you can pass multiple ids like this

```
/employee=[id1,id2]
```