# client.DeleteAsync - include object in body

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website - in C# client code I am using HttpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(path, myObject) fine to call a Json API (the API is also mine created in Web API).

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mydomain");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/something", myObj);
```

I would like to do the same with a Delete verb. However `client.DeleteAsync` does not allow an object to be passed in the body. (I would like to record the reason for deletion alongside the Id of the item to delete in the URI).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can I know why you want to pass an Object in Delete method ? You can pass an Id in your URL

Comment: pass it as a parameter. and reconstruct your complex object model on the action

Comment: Because I may be sending lots of additional information - like reasons for the deletion. I would rather not pass a lot of information in the URI. Is this possible in the body of a delete?

Comment: @niico, No. HTTP DELETE requests do not allow a request body.

Comment: OK - so what do people do if they want to include reasons for the deletion - just pass it in the URI and I guess keep it shorter? Or do they just not use DELETE and use POST instead say?

Comment: @niico, It Depends. And that is more a matter of opinion.

Comment: @niico take a look at some of the answers here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323716/restful-alternatives-to-delete-request-body

Comment: I am more partial to `DELETE /api/path/{id}/{reason}` but again (primarily opinion based)

Comment: doesn't DELETE /api/path/{id}/{reason} violate REST rules?!

Comment: @niico for strict REST yes. it would make the api Rest-ful.

Comment: @Nkosi Perhaps "rest-ish" might be a better word for it ;) As there is no perfect solution here this may be a good option, going to consider this thanks.

Comment: A 3rd option to consider it is the query string. Putting it in the path violates REST in that it's not part of the resource's identity/location, so I would not do that. Since it's just a single string value, query string would be my first choice, body my second.

Comment: seems like there is little agreement on this - and therefore no best practice exists?!

Comment: RFC 7231 stipulates: "DELETE - No defined body semantics." - so body is a bad idea no?

Comment: sorry I will quote it directly - not somebody's analysis of it from another question "A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics"

Comment: Ah, I missed that when searching the spec, wasn't trying to be nit picky :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You'll have to give up a little in terms of convenience since the higher-level `DeleteAsync` doesn't support a body, but it's still pretty straightforward to do it the "long way":

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage {
    Method = HttpMethod.Delete,
    RequestUri = new Uri("http://mydomain/api/something"),
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like using body in a DELETE is unconventional and therefore not a good idea though?!

Comment: Not typical but not unheard of. I got a [request](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/91) to accommodate it in my Flurl library not long ago.

Comment: Apparently RFC 7231 stipulates: "DELETE - No defined body semantics." - seems a bad idea going against standards no?

Comment: Where in the spec did you see that? I'm looking at it right now and I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: answer by alix axel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905916/payloads-of-http-request-methods?rq=1

Comment: So the spec does't say it, and even if it did that's very different from saying it's not allowed, which is certainly is. That said, I concede that it further supports your argument that it's unconventional, and reinforces my recommendation to put it in the query string.

Comment: sorry I will quote it directly - not somebody's analysis of it from another question "A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics"

Comment: querystring is interesting - but super gross, but then what isn't. I feel like all options have been presented to me at this point - there's no perfect solution to this, everything is a compromise?!

Comment: The fact c# doesn't provide a body in a client.DeleteAsync is also an indication that it is a bit naughty / unconventional right?

Comment: Agreed. Capturing a reason for a delete is a very valid use case, and using the query string is the lesser of 3 evils in my mind.

Comment: If you make a new answer with the querystring suggestion I'll accept it - thx.

Comment: I would but that wouldn't answer the question you asked. This one does, which is more useful to others who find it via search. If the querystring suggestion was helpful, cool, I don't need points for it. :)

Comment: Lol ok - I think intent wise it does answer it, it's how I will solve this and maybe how others will too - but of course your call.

Comment: A bit late to the party but I just need to do this for a batched-delete where the body was a json collection of int's for the productids I wanted deleted.

Comment: Exactly the same. Blocking Delete content force to do unit deletion... How should we do a batch of deletes ?