# Swagger Editor showing schema error: is not exactly one from definitions

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-editor

Swagger editor showing the following error in the input JSON.

Schema error at paths./accord/stakeholderMaster/stakeholderLocationDetails.get.parameters[0]
is not exactly one from <#/definitions/parameter>,<#/definitions/jsonReference>

Here is my JSON,

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "description"
  },
  "basePath": "/api",
  "paths": {
    "/accord/stakeholderMaster/stakeholderLocationDetails": {
      "get": {
        "description": "Returns stakeholder location details",
        "operationId": "findMovies",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "stakeHolderId",
            "description": "Stakeholder ID",
            "required": true,
            "type": "integer",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/stakeHolder"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/stakeHolder"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "stakeHolder": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "stakeHolderId": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "chartTerm": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "label": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "chartContent": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "countSeriesOne": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "nameSeriesOne": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "chartLimit": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "receivableChartTerm": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "payableChartTerm": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "chartTerm": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "urlList": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by an incorrect combination of `in`, `type` and `schema` keywords in the parameter definition.

First of all, your operation is GET but has a request body (`"in": "body"` parameter). Request body in GET [does not have defined semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905916/113116).

I guess `stakeHolderId` is supposed to be either a path parameter:

```
GET /.../stakeholderLocationDetails/{stakeHolderId}
```

or a query parameter:

```
GET /.../stakeholderLocationDetails?stakeHolderId=12345
```

So the parameter should be `"in": "path"` or `"in": "query"` instead of `"in": "body"`. In case of a path parameter, also change the path to include the parameter name: `"/accord/stakeholderMaster/stakeholderLocationDetails/{stakeHolderId}"`. In case of a query parameter, leave the path as is (query parameters are not included in paths).

Also remove `schema` from the parameter definition. Path and query parameters use just the `type`; the `schema` keyword is only used for body parameters.

More info:
http://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted.